# Graphviz Networkx - Visualize two different sets of nodes

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graphviz, bipartite

I have two different sets of nodes (red and gray ones), where gray >> red and also red nodes are connected with each other. I tried to draw the graph as a bipartite graph with red nodes on the left side and gray nodes on the right side as shown below. But because gray nodes are many the edges between the gray nodes cannot be displayed. I want to be able to see the red nodes connected to the gray nodes, but be displayed on a different sides alone, and the edges between the gray nodes. Any suggestions how to draw the graph ?

```
color_map = []
one_side_nodes = []
for node in c:
    strnode = str(node)
    if strnode.startswith("m"):
        color_map.append('red')
        one_side_nodes.append(node)
    else:
        color_map.append('gray')

nx.draw(c, pos=nx.bipartite_layout(c, one_side_nodes),node_size=20,scale= 2, node_color=color_map, with_labels=False)
```

[image: enter code here]

Comment: How may red nodes and how many gray?  What output format?  Would you consider running your nodes horizontally?  Would you consider splitting the gray rank into multiple (sub) ranks?

Comment: @sroush red nodes for example can be 20 and gray nodes 100..Running them horizontally i think will no make difference to visualisation.. Also how can i accomplish multiple sub ranks?

Comment: I don't use the networkx interface, but on a quick read, I don't see how to split into sub-ranks  (hard enough with straight graphviz).  I would suggest changing align to horizontal and using SVG as output format.

Comment: @sroush What do you mean by aligning horizontally?

Comment: as I read the spec for bipartite_layout, it allows a third parameter to set align to horizontal https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.bipartite_layout.html?highlight=bipartite_layout#networkx.drawing.layout.bipartite_layout